# Kendo source filter is not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, durandal

Here I am my filter is not working. I am getting following error while the code is posting data to controller.

Error:

> An unknown function with name 'contains' was found. This may also be a
>   key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.

Code:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    txt = $("#Where").val();
    filter = "contains(Title,'"+txt+"')";              
    return db.cards('content', page || 1, null, filter).then(function (d) {   
        vm.widgetData.records(d);
    });            
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume db.cards is one module of yours, but a well formed filter looks like this:

```
var filter=  { field: "Title", operator: "contains", value: txt };
datasource.filter(filter);
```

the operator contains exists:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.operator